# PostgreSQL doesn't recursively revoke roles

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 on Windows 7 SP1 64bit, and I have a problem when revoking roles.
Let's say I have three users: taylor, michelle and the superuser postgres.
As postgres, I grant the role 'utente' to taylor with admin option

```
--postgres@localhost:5432
GRANT utente TO taylor WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Then, as taylor, I grant the role utente to michelle

```
--taylor@localhost:5432
GRANT utente TO michelle;
```

Finally, as postgres, I revoke the role utente from taylor

```
--postgres@localhost:5432
REVOKE utente FROM taylor
```

The role should have been recursively revoked from michelle too, cause she received the role from taylor only. But it isn't so, taylor loses the role but michelle keeps it. I tried to run the command with the RESTRICT option, which should prevent it from being executed, but it doesn't work, the command is executed exactly in the same way, taylor loses the role and michelle keeps it.
Can anyone explain me this please?

Thanks.

Comment: *"The role should have been recursively revoked from michelle too, cause she received the role from taylor only"*. That's a big assumption. In many cases that'd be very much the *wrong* thing to do. Imagine that taylor sets up michelle's user account then leaves the company. You don't want taylor's access revoked.

Comment: Indeed by default it should apply the RESTRICT option and don't execute the command, telling me there are dependent privileges/roles that would be revoked. If I use the CASCADE option instead it should remove all the roles granted by the user from which I'm revoking, but it doesn't do so. I can't understand why.

Comment: Did you tried to do `REVOKE  ADMIN OPTION FOR taylor CASCADE;` *before* doing `REVOKE utente FROM taylor CASCADE;`?

Comment: Yes, but it does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RESTRICT` option is implicitly applied by PostgreSQL, so you don't have to explicitly specify it.

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html):

> A user can only revoke privileges that were granted directly by that user. If, for example, user A has granted a privilege with grant option to user B, and user B has in turned granted it to user C, then user A cannot revoke the privilege directly from C. Instead, user A could revoke the grant option from user B and use the CASCADE option so that the privilege is in turn revoked from user C.

So:

```
REVOKE utente FROM taylor CASCADE;
```

But as you point out, this does not work. Looks like it is either a bug or an error in the documentation.

In a clean run:

```
patrick@puny:~$ psql -d pfams
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

pfams=# SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION postgres;
SET
pfams=# CREATE ROLE utente NOLOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
pfams=# CREATE ROLE taylor LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
pfams=# CREATE ROLE michelle LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
pfams=# GRANT utente TO taylor WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ROLE
pfams=# SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION taylor;
SET
pfams=> GRANT utente TO michelle;
GRANT ROLE
pfams=# SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION postgres;
SET
pfams=# REVOKE utente FROM taylor CASCADE;
REVOKE ROLE
pfams=# \du taylor
           List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of
-----------+------------+-----------
 taylor    |            | {}

pfams=# \du michelle
           List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of
-----------+------------+-----------
 michelle  |            | {utente}
```

Perhaps something to report to the PostgreSQL bugs mailing list.

Comment: I've already tried this but it doesn't work, it does exactly the same things, revokes from taylor but not from michelle

Comment: @DevOlly You are right, looks like a bug. See expanded answer above.